# Problem with Output with Static keyword in C/C++

Tags: c++, static

Output wrt my reasoning should be 0456 but the compiler shows 0415 and I debugged it a little and realised it is targeting both "i" differently.

I'll be grateful if someone can explain the reasoning behind it.
Thank You :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    static int i;
    for(int j = 0; j<2; j++)
    {
        cout << i++;
        static int i = 4;
        cout << i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have 2 different `i` variables. I recommend you debug again and do it more carefully meaning step through the code 1 line at a time looking at the flow and the value of `i` at each step.

Comment: Finally someone who uses a debugger before asking, nice question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should expect the output to be as follow:

- Loop pass #1: print `0` (top-level block scope `i`) followed by `4` (for loop block scope `i`).
- Loop pass #2: print `1` (top-level block scope `i`) followed by `5` (for loop block scope `i`).

Thus `0415`.

```
static int i;          // declares i at block-scope; denote as (i1)
for(int j = 0; j<2; j++)
{                      // enter nested block scope

    cout << i++;       // at this point, `i` local to current
                       // block scope is yet to be declared.
                       // thus, this refers to (i1)

    static int i = 4;  // this declares a local `i` (denote as (i2))
                       // which shadows (i1) henceforth

    cout << i++;       // this refers to (i2)
}
```

Even if the *lifetime* of the local static variable `i` starts at first loop pass (the first time control passes its declaration) such that its declaration is skipped on the second pass, this does not affect the [*scope*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) of it.

> #### Block scope
>
> The potential scope of a name declared in a block (compound statement) **begins at the point of declaration and ends at the end of the block** [...]

Comment: Thank you @dfrib for the response, but adding to it further, I can rationalise how the answer has 0 followed by 4, but for the second loop, why is the first "i" treated as i1 and not "i2"? 
I think that because in the next loop (loop #2), we have defined that there is "i2" which overshadows "i1" in the scope of the loop, so how does the compiler decide whether it's "i1" or "i2"?